# Filter list with dynamic filter column

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

First of all, this requirement is not about the Search Functionality of SharePoint.

I have a requirement wherein the user should be able to search a list.

At first I used the text filter web part to search in a specific column in my list, however, they dont want this kind of approach. What they want is that there will be a textbox and a dropdown that contains a list of columns (lookup to a list). the selected column is where the application will search or filter the list.

What approaches is best here?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you create custom web part using Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes this is what I am planning. if nothing easier works. I will create a textbox with dropdown containing the list of columns in the list where I will be searching.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using query string and some html and JavaScript.

First create a view with query string filtering enabled. Then add a Content Editor web part. Using html add text box, drop-down, and a button. On button click form the query string and using JavaScript post to the same page.

Comment: my problem here is that it will only filter the items in the view. so if I have 10,000 items,and only 100 items per view (pagination) then it will only search/filter the items in the current view. please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are wrong, the filtered data will be on the entire items on the list.

Comment: oh okay, I stand corrected. Can you show me an example on how it is done? it should search a specific column using a wildcard search. so for example I entered letter "a" then it will return all result containing letter "a"

Comment: You can use [this](http://www.sharemuch.com/2013/11/18/sharepoint-silly-questions-filtering-list-view-with-query-string-parameters/) for creating the view.